# Throw exceptions for input in wrong interval or format

Tags: python, exception

I am new to programming and I tried to implement a function which takes a trigonometric function and an angle in degrees as input and outputs the evaluated function in radians. I was wondering how to implement exceptions if the input angle for instance isn`t between 0 and 360 degrees or the input trigonmetric function isn't of a kind sin, cos or tan ?

Here is my first try:

```
def ev_trig_function():
    # input trigonometric function
    trig_func = input('Please insert trigonometric function :')
    # input angle in degrees
    while True:
        try:
            deg = float(input('Please insert angle in degrees :'))
            break

        except ValueError:
            print('degree value must be a float number, try again!')

    if trig_func == 'sin':
        return print('sin(', deg, ') = {}'.format(np.sin(degree_to_rad(deg))), 'rad')
    elif trig_func == 'cos':
        return print('cos(', deg, ') = {}'.format(np.cos(degree_to_rad(deg))), 'rad')
    elif trig_func == 'tan':
        return print('tan(', deg, ') = {}'.format(np.tan(degree_to_rad(deg))), 'rad')
    else :
        return print('Please insert sin, cos or tan as trigonometric function')
```

I was wondering if you could include the else statement in the exceptions somehow ? And how do I make sure that the input angle is in between 0 and 360 degrees, because for now i only checked for the right datatype. I would be happy about a respond.

Cheers

Comment: Why are you just not calling the functions, and let them do the validations?

Comment: because thats the task we have been given .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the angle is between 0 and 360, you can use the following condition:

```
0 <= deg <= 360
```

If it returns False, then you need to ask for another input. With your code so far, I think it should be like this:

```
while True:
        try:
            deg = float(input('Please insert angle in degrees, between 0 and 360 :'))
            if 0 <= deg <= 360:
                break
            else:
                print('Degree should be between 0 and 360.')

        except ValueError:
            print('degree value must be a float number, try again!')
```

In regards to the else statement, you should implement it before the while loop:

```
trig_func = input('Please insert trigonometric function :')

while trig_func not in ['sin', 'cos', 'tan']:
    trig_func = input('Please insert sin, cos or tan as trigonometric function: ')
```

This guarantees that the program won't continue unless the function is either sin, cos, or tan.

A comment about your final segment of code - the print function prints to the screen and returns None. If you wish your function to return the value of the trig function, use return without the print, i.e.:

```
return 'sin(', deg, ') = {}'.format(np.sin(degree_to_rad(deg))), 'rad'
```

If you wish to just print it, use the print without the return, i.e.:

```
print('sin(', deg, ') = {}'.format(np.sin(degree_to_rad(deg))), 'rad')
```

Comment: I did the return as print because it is a task someone will have to check after, but than you for the comment. I really appreciate it.